# How can I get my ID from button to my controller?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

What am I doing wrong?

I want to add a order to an existing customer, but the id for the customer does not go true to the controller.

```cs
public ActionResult AddOrder(Guid? customerId)
{
    if (customerId == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(customerId));
    }

    Customer customer = db.Customer.Find(customerId);

    return View(customer);
}
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>ProductCode</th>
        <th>ProductNaam</th>
        <th>Aantal</th>
        <th>Prijs</th>
        <th>Totaal</th>
    </tr>
    @{
        var totalBill = 0;
    }
    @foreach (var order in item.Order)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@order.ProductCode</td>
            <td>@order.ProductNaam</td>
            <td>@order.Aantal</td>
            <td>@order.Prijs</td>
            <td>@order.Totaal</td>                                  
            <td>@Html.ActionLink(" ", "AddOrder", new { id = order.CustomerId }, 
                new { @class = "btn btn-success pull-right btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-plus" })</td>
        </tr>
        totalBill = totalBill + @Convert.ToInt32(order.Totaal);
    }
</tbody>
```

in live html :

```html
<a class="btn btn-success pull-right btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
    href="/order/AddOrder/96f33a9f-e4e9-4ab1-8b8c-1db2cbc9ce37"> </a>
```

I see the guid, but in the controller it is still `00000000000000000000` - all zeros in the guid instead of the right guid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter in AddOrder is customerId, but from your HTML you are assigning order.CustomerId to id. Try change the id to customerId and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You aren't marrying up the parameter ID with the one in the action i.e. you set `id` but the action expects `customerId`. Try:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
  " ", 
  "AddOrder", 
  new { customerId = order.CustomerId }, 
 ... 
})
```

Comment: I missed that,ty guys!